# How to change buffer name for NeoVim Terminal special buffer

Tags: neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer

If I execute a interactive command with `:terminal`, buffername will be something like: `term://.//1234:command executed here with params`.

I want to be able to change it to something more meaningful to use with my fork for vim-vroom. Here is the snippet for reference:

```
function s:RunNeoTerminal(cmd)
  " close previous openned buffer
  if exists('t:vroom_terminal_bufnr') && bufexists(t:vroom_terminal_bufnr)
    exec ":bd! ".t:vroom_terminal_bufnr
  end

  let height = winheight(0) * 1/4
  exec ":belowright " . height . "split"

  exec ":terminal " . a:cmd
  " terminal runs by default in insert mode which kills the buffer after exit,
  " let's change to normal mode
  exec ":stopinsert"
  let t:vroom_terminal_bufnr = bufnr('%')
endfunction
```

https://github.com/brodock/vim-vroom/blob/neovim-terminal/autoload/vroom.vim#L253-L267

Answer (score 7):

You can change the name of **any** buffer by using the [`:file {name}`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Afile_f) command.  However, doing so changes that alternate-file to the previous name, which you may not want in this case.  The [`:keepalt`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Akeepalt) command avoids that issue.

Putting it all together, this should do what you want

```
keepalt file meaningful
```